# Break long word with CSS

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, break, long-integer

I have a situation where there can be long words like 'hellowordsometext' or integer like '1234567891122' without any space in between. check this js please. http://jsfiddle.net/rzq5e/6/

how is it possible to break it in to next line after it reach the div width. what happens now is, it spans out out along with th div

```
<div>Solutionforentprise</div>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What you need is `word-wrap: break-word;`, this property will force the non spaced string to break inside the `div`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rzq5e/7/)

```
div {
   width: 20px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Will this work in all major browsers ? can you pls tell what are the browsers it want

Answer (score 21):

I have found this solution my self.

```
word-break: break-all;
```

but it doesn't work for Opera.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break

Answer (score 9):

The other answers have some problems with old browsers, like before Chrome 32.

Its better to use this code:

```
  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
```

You can also add a hyphen where the word breaks *(if supported)*:

```
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)

```css
.c1 {
   width: 200px;
   border: 1px solid;

  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;

  /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
For more information, please visit: http://csstricks.com/thisisanonexistentandreallylongurltoaddtoanytextinfactwhyareyoustillreadingit.
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

give an id or class to your div

then

```
#divid
{
width: 30px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Word-wrap is supported in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, and WebKit browsers such as Chrome and Safari, Opera 10.5+.

Comment: Will this work in all major browsers ? can you pls tell what are the browsers it want

Comment: @mazraara Word-wrap is supported in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, and WebKit browsers such as Chrome and Safari.

Comment: thanks a lot. what about Opera ? also is this feature comes with css3 ?

Comment: check this out https://caniuse.com/?search=word-wrap%3A%20break-word

Answer (score 3):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rzq5e/11/)**

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 20px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix the size of the DIV and apply 'overflow: hidden'
so it will not effect the grid size an all na.

```
div{width: 40px;
overflow: hidden;}
```

do you need to view entire text?