# How to break long strings in HTML?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I read (and tried):

1. [Break long word with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628038/break-long-word-with-css)

And I now have:

```
<span style="font-size: xx-small; white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; white-space: -pre-wrap;white-space:
-o-pre-wrap;white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-all;white-space:normal;width: 385px;">
```

but still the large strings will NOT auto wrap in FF or IE but it DOES in Chrome...

(example: http://ed.je/2L6 or http://jsfiddle.net/92kSU/ )

Comment: Please share a JSFiddle

Comment: What kinds of strings would you want to break and by which principles? For example, do you want norma l words t o be br oken at a ribra ry points? (Many “solutions” offered to abstract questions like this do such things.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case it looks like you need to set `word-break: break-all` at a higher level. If I open your example page in Firefox and use Firebug to set style `word-break: break-all` on `.entry-content` then the large strings wrap.

*Edit*:

Alternatively, you could instead set the display style of you spans as inline-block.

Comment: Didn't see your edit before adding my answer. Upvote for you.

Comment: tnx. slowly updating new style.css. probably best to set it at style.css level and not post level.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet is a catch-all for word-wrapping:

```
.class_name {
     -ms-word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-all;

     /* Non standard for webkit */
     word-break: break-word;

     -webkit-hyphens: auto;
     -moz-hyphens: auto;
     -ms-hyphens: auto;
     hyphens: auto;
}
```

`word-break: break-all` will work except for IE8 and Firefox, so you need the `ms-word-break` prefixed line included as well. As usual, IE8 requires that its prefixed line be added first. This doesn't solve it for Firefox, however.

In FF, you need to use a new item called `hyphenations`, which is supported except for Chrome (but it's okay, because Chrome will use the basic `word-break: break all`) in this lengthy list: `-webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; -ms-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto;`.

`Hyphenation` will insert hyphens at the correct location for word-breaks, which is a better solution than just splitting a word in two.

[More information on why this is a catch all.](http://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/)

Comment: Downvoter please comment; this is in fact a catch-all for word-wrapping and when applied to the OP's code will break the long strings.

Comment: tnx would also work. gave you an upvote to match to whoever downvoted