# Table inside Flexbox Wider than the Page

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble with having a table inside a flexbox layout bleeding outside the parent flexbox making the page wider than the browser width. This is kind of a mockup showing the similar problem that I am having.

```css
#flex {
  display:flex;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#one {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
}
#two {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div id="one">one
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>First Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Fourth Row</td>
        <td>Fifth Row</td>
        <td>Sixth Row</td>
        <td>Seventh Row</td>
        <td>Eighth Row</td>
        <td>Ninth Row</td>
        <td>Tenth Row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>DataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataData</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that even though `.flex` is just the width of the screen, `.two` is much wider.

I am using datatables inside the second div so the table size is dynamic, and even with setting max widths to the child and everything, I cannot get it to stop bleeding out. I need help figuring out how I can lock down the second div of the flexbox to let the table resize correctly (it has responsive elements, but doesn't get used b/c it just goes wide).

edit: It seems like the table is doing the full 100% width of the page, but then is going outside the margin on the right side because of the element on the left.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just remove `width: 110%`?

Comment: yeah... not really sure what you were expecting.  110% is wider than 100% and will then overflow.

Comment: I think you should put the real elements on this example instead of this 110% div.

Comment: Ah.  I feel dumb now.  It's just to simulate the overly wide content from the actual code.  The trouble is that it's hard to tell what's making it overflow or if there's anything that can be done to fix it without the actual code that's causing the problem.  Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: Kk, let me try and make a better example. Essentially, it is the datatables javascript that when it builds the table, it is making it too wide.

Comment: Usualy tables arent responsive, they only gets a scroll on small screens...

Comment: @JosephMarikle ok added an update. See how the extra data in the table causes it to bleed to the right? My table does the same. It has responsive elements that are supposed to shrink it, but it doesn't feel those constraints. Also, If i delete the element on the left, everything works just fine, so its only when that element exists it bleeds out

Comment: @David I see.  Is it character data that is causing the bleed?  If it's something that doesn't really need to be broken up logically, freestock.tk's suggestion would work.  Maybe add it to the offending cell or column?  This is basically what I'm suggesting but without inlining the style: http://codepen.io/jmarikle/pen/mPdeRy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, set the body:

```
body {  
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Then, let the biggest container `#flex { max-width: 100%;` and your `table { word-break: break-all;`

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZYpEK)

Comment: @David about the word wrap, [**check this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378970/word-break-prefer-normal-but-if-not-possible-break-all)

Answer (score 9):

The answer above didn't work for me, but what did work:

I had problems because the two tables were directly into the flexbox container. Apparently the tables automatically take the same size that the div surrounding it, even though this is a flexbox container...

So, **Just put two div's inside your flexbox and put the table inside the div:**

```
<div style="display:flex;">
    <div><table> table content </table></div>
    <div><table> table content </table></div>
</div>
```

Then if you still have problems, make sure your table has this CSS:

```
table{
  width: 100% !important;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: `table-layout: fixed;`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, table was an indirect descendant of flex, so 
`<div class="table-wrapper" style="overflow: auto;"><table></table></div>` - doesn't work (page still overflowed by table) 
Solution is to put `overflow: auto;` on the direct flex child

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I have a table with `table-layout: fixed` that is wrapped up by another div inside of a flexbox child. In this case, you have to constrain the immediate flexbox child by applying `min-width` or `overflow`. The example below uses `min-width`. Without it, the `overflow` in `div` with class `childofchild2` will not work.

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.child1 {
  width: 50px;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.childofchild2 {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.child3 {
  width: 50px;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table td {
  border: solid 1px;
}

td {
  width: 1000px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Left</div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="childofchild2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>First Column</td>
          <td>Second Column</td>
          <td>Third Column</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data Data </td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=`enter code here`"child3">Right</div>
</div>
```