# Bootstrap 4 - word wrapping in cards

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How can I word wrap text insided cards.

Here's the problem: [plunker link](https://embed.plnkr.co/EXVeBhLwwGhJ8lM0NTh8/)

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hasn't this [already been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628038/break-long-word-with-css)? It's really a CSS issue and not specfic to Bootstrap.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need two rules:

- `max-width` for your `.card` elements (because without defining a width CSS will not know where to break your long word) **or** `overflow: hidden;` to make the `.card` width no longer depend on the long word length
- `word-wrap: break-word;` to tell the browser to break a word

---

```css
.card {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.card-text {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

---

```css
.card {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card-block {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">supportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingsupportingto additional content. This card has even longer content than the
          first to show that equal height action.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
/* For screens above: 576px */
.card{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-text{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/BEbJehY8hkWpDoTfFJXz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Also consider this (for URLs etc); from the docs:

> For longer content, you can add a .text-truncate class to truncate the text with an ellipsis. Requires display: inline-block or display: block.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/

Comment: But that would render the "descrition" text to a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this would work too:

```
.card-text {
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: normal;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

See [this discussion](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9130) for additional info.