# Bootstrap 4 - Column rendered to new line

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've got a tricky problem using bootstrap 4.

In the following example, I have a row with two columns. 
The first one contains a very long text without any space. The second one contains a small one, specified as "col-auto".

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="background-color: red; width: 500px;" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    THIS_IS_A_SUPER_LONG_TEXT_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    RIGHT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

But, unfortunately, my columns are rendered on two distinct lines, as shown in the example below.

[image]

Instead, I would like my text to wrap, and display something like that (without the spaces):

[image]

Do you know if this possible? If yes, which CSS property should I apply on which tag? I searched for something like forcing the `width:auto` attribute to be effective, but I don't know how.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a line break in a loooooong word in a DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-loooooong-word-in-a-div)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Break long word with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628038/break-long-word-with-css)

Comment: Add class  text-break to your column with the long text. ie: <div class="col text-break"> You second column div should be <div class="col col-auto">

Comment: This should work <div class="col"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-auto"> YOUR BIG TEXT </div> </div> </div> and for small text <div class="col-auto"> SMALL TEXT </div>

Answer (score 2):

**Use break-word:**

Since `col` will let bootstrap handle the grid automatically this is not achievable with `col` and the only thing you can do is adding `break-word` to `col` class and avoid the text to overflow the parent `div`.

```css
.col {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="background-color: red; width: 500px;" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        THIS_IS_A_SUPER_LONG_TEXT_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        RIGHT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Use bootstrap col-x-x:**

On the other hand, you can achieve it with `col-6` and add it to both child `div` to let the browser now there is two-column with the same height in the same `row` but since your text is too long you still have to add `break-word` to the related div to avoid further mess up. For better understanding bootstrap grid and find the better solution to fit your exact need I suggest to read get the bootstrap document from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) or w3school document on bootstrap grid system from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp).
Here's the snippet to let it happen:

```css
div.row>div:first-of-type.col-6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="background-color: red;" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        THIS_IS_A_SUPER_LONG_TEXT_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        RIGHT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE:** to avoid further issues I suggest to remove `width: 500px;` from the parent division.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap's `.text-break` if text is a plain text.

```
.text-break {
  word-break: break-word !important; // IE & < Edge 18
  overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="background-color: red; width: 500px;" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-break">
        THIS_IS_A_SUPER_LONG_TEXT_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        RIGHT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If it is `preformatted` text, `text-break` does not work. And since bootstrap does not have any class that wraps long preformatted text, you need to write some custom CSS.

```
.pre-text-wrap  {
  white-space: normal !important;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```css
.pre-text-wrap {
  white-space: normal !important;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="background-color: red; width: 500px;" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <pre class="pre-text-wrap">
                     THIS_IS_A_SUPER_LONG_TEXT_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
</pre>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        RIGHT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Or you may use bootstrap's `.text-wrap` and only `word-break: break-all;`.

```
.text-break-all {
   word-break: break-all;
}
```