# Wrapping the long text inside datagrid/Xgrid column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Though I have used the below code for Datagrid columns of materail UI,
I cannot wrap the text inside the column. It just appearing on single line instead of wrapping into multiple lines.

Anyone help me with solution how can I wrap text in column of datagrid or xgrid using materail ui.

const message ="AsuperLongTextWithNoSpaceItIsVeryAnnoyingIWantToWrapThisSentence"

```
          <Grid item>

          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs zeroMinWidth>


            <Typography style={{overflowWrap: 'break-word'}}>{message}</Typography>


          </Grid>


        </Grid>
```

Comment: [Break long word with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18628038/2873538)

Comment: Your code sample seems incomplete